# Profile Directory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profile

I am seeing unusual behavior when trying to insert a profile as a directory on the front end of WP.

https://my.url.org/state-chairs/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&force=1&gid=21

https://my.url.org/states/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&force=1&gid=19

They should be showing two different data sets but are only showing the same data? I checked that the profile has the proper group selected.

Also it says as an admin I do not have permission to access this page: https://my.url.org/states/ When I visit there it says:

> Permission Denied You do not have permission to view this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance.

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.27 on WP 4.9.1. This is a multisite.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be more specific about how you're trying to achieve your goal. Have you tried using a shortcode? Or are you relying on the querystring to be present?

Comment: This is using a shortcode: e.g. [civicrm component="profile" gid="19" mode="view" hijack="0"]

Answer (score 2):

Ah, that moment when you bump into a question you figured out but I forgot I even posted it here.

There may be other methods but you should use the native CiviCRM profile link which you can find at Administer > Profiles > more > Use- Listings Mode. This looks like: https://example.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM..." format or whatever you set your base page at.

The issue seems to be if you try and use a shortcode for this directory style listing and not use the CiviCRM base page. So, you can create a clean URL to redirect to the native CiviCRM profile link. Perhaps this is considered a workaround but it works :)